# Trying to plot a CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

I'm trying to plot a CSV file, and this is what it looks like:

```
Date    Ebola: Case counts and deaths from the World Health Organization and WHO situation reports
3/22/2014   49
3/24/2014   86
3/25/2014   86
3/26/2014   86
3/27/2014   103
3/28/2014   112
3/29/2014   112
3/31/2014   122
4/1/2014    127
4/4/2014    143
4/7/2014    151
4/9/2014    158
4/11/2014   159
4/14/2014   168
4/16/2014   197
4/17/2014   203
4/20/2014   208
4/23/2014   218
4/26/2014   224
5/1/2014    226
5/3/2014    231
5/5/2014    235
5/7/2014    236
5/10/2014   233
5/12/2014   248
5/23/2014   258
5/27/2014   281
5/28/2014   291
6/1/2014    328
6/3/2014    344
6/10/2014   351
6/16/2014   398
6/18/2014   390
6/20/2014   390
6/30/2014   413
7/2/2014    412
7/6/2014    408
7/8/2014    409
7/12/2014   406
7/14/2014   411
7/17/2014   410
7/20/2014   415
7/23/2014   427
7/27/2014   460
7/30/2014   472
```

I imported it into my MATLAB workspace. Now I want to plot this data using MATLAB, but how do I do this? The variables I have for each column are `Date` and `EbolaCaseCountsAndDeathsFromTheWorldHealthOrganizationAndWHOsit` (sorry I don't know how to make the latter variable shorter).

I tried doing `plot(Date, EbolaCa[...])` but it gives me an error. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: An error message would be helpful...

Comment: Assuming the dates are strings they need to be converted before you can plot them. See: [Dates and Time as Numbers and Strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/dates-and-time-as-numeric-values.html)

Comment: Your `dates` would still be as strings. They will need to be converted to `datetime` before you can use them.

Comment: @RandomGuy So would it be `plot(datenum(Date), EbolaCase...)`?

Comment: @excaza I tried `plot(datenum(Date), EbolaCase...)` but then I got `Error using datevec...Failed to lookup month of year`.

Comment: Tell it the [date format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_formatIn).

Comment: @excaza I can't tell if the format should be `mm/dd/yyyy` or `m/dd/yyyy` since there are dates that have a single character month (`7/23/2014`) and ones that have two (`12/23/2014`). Which one do I use?

Comment: Read the documentation. A single `m` is `Month using capitalized first letter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use both `datenum()` and `datetick()` to actually show dates on the x-axis. I was able to create your table snippet as follows:

```
T={'3/22/2014'   49
'3/24/2014'   86
'3/25/2014'   86
'3/26/2014'   86
'3/27/2014'   103
'3/28/2014'   112
'3/29/2014'   112
'3/31/2014'   122
'4/1/2014'    127
'4/4/2014'    143
'4/7/2014'    151
'4/9/2014'    158
'4/11/2014'   159
'4/14/2014'   168
'4/16/2014'   197
'4/17/2014'   203
'4/20/2014'   208
'4/23/2014'   218
'4/26/2014'   224
'5/1/2014'    226
'5/3/2014'    231
'5/5/2014'    235
'5/7/2014'    236
'5/10/2014'   233
'5/12/2014'   248
'5/23/2014'   258
'5/27/2014'   281
'5/28/2014'   291
'6/1/2014'    328
'6/3/2014'    344
'6/10/2014'   351
'6/16/2014'   398
'6/18/2014'   390
'6/20/2014'   390
'6/30/2014'   413
'7/2/2014'    412
'7/6/2014'    408
'7/8/2014'    409
'7/12/2014'   406
'7/14/2014'   411
'7/17/2014'   410
'7/20/2014'   415
'7/23/2014'   427
'7/27/2014'   460
'7/30/2014'   472};
T=cell2table(T);
T.Properties.VariableNames={'Date','Ebola'};
```

where the first column is composed by strings and the second column is composed by numbers. To generate the `plot()` you might want to do something like

```
figure(1);
plot(datenum(T.Date,'m/dd/yyyy'),T.Ebola);
datetick('x','dd/mmm/yyyy'); grid on;
```

which shows

[image]

However, feel free to adjust `datenum()` and `datetick()` format(s) as you wish.

Comment: The date can be either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `m/dd/yyyy`. How do I express this as a format?

Comment: This approach works even with 2-digits months. I tried adding a new value in October 2014 and it was added to the plot. No problems.

Comment: I get the error `Failed on converting date string to date number` for the code `plot(datenum(Date, 'm/dd/yyyy'), Ebola)`.

Comment: Those are the variables that represent the columns in the CSV file. When I imported the file MATLAB gave me these two variables.

Comment: I understand that. Type in the Command Window `class(Date)` and `class(Ebola)`. What's the output?

Comment: `class(Date)` gives `cell` and `class(Ebola)` gives `double`.

Comment: hmm, on Matlab R2015b this code works with both 1-digit and 2-digits months. You can as well try to set all 1-digit months into 2-digits months by appending a leading zero (that is, January will be `01` instead of `1` and so on) and see if that works for you

Comment: How do I append a 0?

Comment: `string=['0' string]`. In this manner if `string='3/24/2014'`, it will become '03/24/2014'`. However, you should do this operation only if the month has only 1-digit.

Comment: I have no idea how I would make sure it has only one digit.

Comment: Well. Have a look at the position of the first slash. If the date has the format xx/xx/xxxx then the third element of such string is a slash. As instead if the date has the format x/xx/xxxx, the second element is now a slash whereas in the previous case the second element was a digit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out. BTW how do I plot two CSV's on the same graph? Sorry if it's getting off topic, this is the last thing I have to do. :)

Comment: You can use either a `subplot()` or the `hold on` command. The `subplot()` will open on the same figure two different plots. With the `hold on` command (which is `plot(<first plot>); hold on; plot(<second plot>);`) you actually draw two lines on the same plot.